# How can I generate a "general" structure for an R list?

Tags: r, list

I have an R list is fairly nested, but it does have "records". I'd like to be able to produce an overview of the R list (for displaying in a browser, etc.).  What I'd like is something like the output of `str()` but having the fields from each record summarized. In a sense, I'd like to construct a new nested object where the values of the leaves are the `summary()` of all the values found in that list element in the same logical location throughout the records.  As a simple example, if I had:

```
list(a1 = list (b = 1, d = 3, g = 'abc', x = list( j1 = 1, j2 = 2),
     a2 = list (b = 17, d = 5, f = 9, g = 'def'))
```

I'd like to return a list that summarizes the number of times that a list element was present:

```
list(b = 2, 
     d = 2, 
     f = 1, 
     g = 2 , 
     x = list (j1 = 1, j2 = 1))
```

The idea is to give a high-level overview of a large and complex R list that could be easily displayed.

Comment: I think just `unlist(l)` will give you a pretty clear picture. Or maybe `table(sub(".*\\.", "", names(unlist(l))))`. Other than that, I don't understand why you keep `x` as a list while `a1` and `a2` were unlisted

Comment: `table(gsub(".*\\.", "", names(unlist(l))))` that exactly what he is looking for David. `x` was a typo

Comment: Thanks, @DavidArenburg and @joel.wilson. Pretty close and enough to get me there.  I replaced the `".*\\."` with `"[^.]*\\."` to take out only the first level of the list. Now, I just need to take the names back to a nested list.  Thanks for the suggestion of unlisting.